# Reference External Modules in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, reactjs

I have an application which I want to convert step by step to TypeScript. Currently we are using browserify to generate a bundle.

When converting to TypeScript I am having some modules which have not yet been converted. In the [TypeScript Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-working-with-other-javascript-libraries) it says that I can reference external modules, when specifying a type definition file for it.

I have a module A.js which is not yet converted to TypeScript. I have a global type definition file which defines

```
declare module "A" {
    export function foo();
    export function bar();
}
```

I am importing my module like this:

```
///<reference path="../../typings/NotYetConvertedModules.d.ts" />
import A = require('../someFolder/A');
```

when compiling this I get

```
error TS2307: Cannot find external module '../someFolder/A'
```

When requiring it with `require('A')` the compilation step works but the module loader cannot find the file, since I am not having a global alias for it.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you declare a module name in quotes, the quoted name becomes the alias. So when you write...

```
declare module 'A' { //...
```

You import it using the following (no matter where you are importing it):

```
import a = require('A');
```

This is useful when creating definitions for node.js modules, for example.

You cannot use a string alias with a relative path, so you can't have:

```
declare module '../SomeFolder/A' { //...
```

But you can place a definition file named `a.d.ts` in the appropriate location (SomeFolder).

The file `./SomeFolder/a.d.ts` looks like this:

```
declare module A {
    export function foo();
    export function bar();
}

export = A;
```

The file `./Scripts/AnotherFolder/example.ts` looks like this:

```
import A = require('../../SomeFolder/A');
```

You will need to adjust the path based on your exact folder structure, but you can see the idea. Importantly, you don't need the `reference` comment when importing the module from the same folder as the definition file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using external modules (which means that the module ID depends on the file name)

Instead of writing in ../../typings/NotYetConvertedModules.d.ts

```
declare module "A" {
    export function foo();
    export function bar();
}
```

you should rather simply write in ../someFolder/A.d.ts

```
export function foo();
export function bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to shy away from relative paths when using typescript for references. Maybe it is just me, but I find it buggy (for referencing).

In your require.js configuration, you can map the request string to a predefined list of files, or some similar system. For example `require("document.text")` could see `"document"` and map that to `src/net/unicorns/document/text.js`

This allows you to debug issues quickly too (typescript compiler errors are annoying).

Hope this helps.